# Second select query not working

Tags: php

the second query is not being executed no matter what. I tried removing the first query and executing the second only but still. This is happening incase of select queries only.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$func=$_GET['func'];
if($func=="login")
{
    $u=$_POST['name'];
    $p=$_POST['pwd'];
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from user where usr_id='$u' & usr_pwd='$p'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $query1=mysqli_query($con,"select * from usradmin where usr_id='$u' & usr_pwd='$p'");
    $row1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
   if($u==NULL || $p==NULL)
   {
       echo "Feilds Cennot Be Empty";
   }
   else
       {

    if($u==$row['usr_id'] && $p==$row['usr_pwd'])
    {
        echo "Login Success";
    }
    else if($u==$row1['usr_id'] && $p==$row1['usr_pwd'])
    {
        echo "Admin Login Success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Login Failed";
    }
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you try to run the second query? Is `useradmin` supposed to be `useradmin`? Hard to tell what's going wrong without any error.

Comment: so what your `usradmin` table looks like?

Comment: nope. the echo statement is supposed to be the input for span tag via ajax.both the table cotain only usr_id and usr_pwd

Comment: You are not giving us enough information. What is happening when you try to execute this? Are you getting "Login Failed"? Are you getting any errors in console? How do you know the second query "isn't running"?

Comment: I think you meant `and` instead of `&` in both of your queries (though I'm not sure if that relates to the problem you're having).

Comment: if i login using usr_id and usr_pwd of first table it should "Login Success" in span tag. But if i use from second table t shows "Login Failed"

Comment: Where is that bobby tables guy...these queries are open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: thanks smarx it was as you mentioned. I've just started learning but i'll check for silly mistakes next time properly.